# Does datetime account for the Calendar (New Style) Act of 1750?

Tags: python, datetime, calendar

In September of 1752, in accordance with the Calendar (New Style) Act of 1750, 11 days were skipped in September 1752. This can be seen with the Unix cal command.

```
$ cal 9 1752
September 1752
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
1 2 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

After learning this factoid, I wondered if Python's datetime class accounted for this at all. After some quick toying around, it appears as if it does not...

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(1752, 9, 14)
datetime.timedelta(96550, 47314, 535334)
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(1752, 9, 2)
datetime.timedelta(96562, 47318, 183610)
```

By my understanding, if Sept. 14, 1752 was 96550 days ago, than Sept. 2, 1752 should be 96551 days ago (because the 3-13 were skipped).

I also appears as if the calendar class also does not account for the skip

```
>>> calendar.prmonth(1752, 9)
   September 1752
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

It is likely inconsequential in the vast majority of applications, however it still seems like a bug to me that this is not accounted for. Of course, it is also entirely possible that I am missing something obvious.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is why I'm terrified to ever touch timestamps.... I'll throw character encoding in that list too

Comment: It's quite rare to find date handling in *any* language that works properly before the introduction of the Gregorian calendar, it just isn't needed often enough to be worth the complication. And according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) the skip happened in 1582. Edit: I see it wasn't adopted by Britain and the U.S. until 1752.

Comment: The Gregorian calendar wasn't adopted everywhere at the same time. Since `datetime` doesn't have any location information or settings, it seems very unlikely. Why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python calendar is described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html), which says:

> Most of these functions and classes rely on the datetime module which
>   uses an idealized calendar, the current Gregorian calendar
>   indefinitely extended in both directions. This matches the definition
>   of the “proleptic Gregorian” calendar in Dershowitz and Reingold’s
>   book “Calendrical Calculations”, where it’s the base calendar for all
>   computations.

So no, England's decision in 1752 to use the Gregorian calendar (like much of the rest of western Europe) instead of the Julian calendar is not reflected in calendar that Python uses. It's quite interesting to me that the Unix `cal` command does include the switch.